Incremental Data Export from SFMC to Adobe CDP
I wanted to talk through the logic for an automation I have, the issue im facing, and hopefully find a solution.
Approach: I have an automation in SMFC that 1)queries for email open data and sends to a data extension (using overwrite data activity) 2) extracts said data to send to the FTP 3) file convert to UTF 8 format 4) transfer file to FTP. I have a data flow in Adobe CDP that ingests this file every hour and the data is visible and actionable on the customer profile.
Issue: The SFTP source connector process will ingest files based upon the timestamp of the file placed into the source path. If you are overwriting the ingestion file with new data, Adobe CDP will observe this as a new file and ingest all of the data in the file. Adobe CDP ingest all records in the file a new records. So the data flow look like 12am - 4 records 1am - records 2am 4- records, etc even if no new data has been added to the file.
My question is is there a way to perform an incremental data load from SFMC to Adobe CDP that only ingests new data and not the whole file every time the data flow runs?
